# How can I prevent iCheck from styling certain checkboxes, while still styling others?

Tags: jquery, css, tablesorter, icheck

I just incorporated iCheck (http://icheck.fronteed.com) into my site in order to replace the bland default checkbox elements on the page with the more visually appealing checkbox styles offered by iCheck.

iCheck is working really well for the most part, but for some reason it's breaking the functionality of the columnselector widget (https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-column-selector.html) that I'm using for tablesorter.

To remedy this, I'd love to style every checkbox on my site using iCheck, EXCEPT for any checkboxes that are part of the columnselector widget. Is there a way to either have iCheck ignore a specific div or checkbox (by adding a class), OR to only have iCheck style checkboxes that are labeled with a specific class?

Thanks in advance for any tips you might be able to suggest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the checkboxes which you want to style and which you do not want to style will have different classes. If not please add an additional class to the checkboxes which are not supposed to be styled.

For example:

```
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" class="dont-style" />

//Adding not to the query selector only selects input's without the *dont-style* class
$('input').not('.dont-style').iCheck({
  labelHover: false,
  cursor: true
});
```

Or else you can just add a class to the checkboxes which you want to style like `styleMe`and then initialize the plugin like this:

```
$('.styleMe').iCheck({
      labelHover: false,
      cursor: true
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Sahil! I really appreciate that you provided two different solutions.I ended up using the second solution that you offered and everything is working perfectly now.